# How to implement color through css from dark to light?

Tags: css

i want to implement color combination from dark to light or light to dark
how to implement that
please check - http://screencast.com/t/zBgFPTOtp7
 please help

Comment: Just search CSS Gradients - you will find you answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's using CSS3 gradients.
This can generate one for you http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
Alternatively if you want to learn how to write them yourself I learnt how to do so here...
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_gradients.asp

Typical use it to say colour A to B. for a DIV with the class mydiv this would look like this (in your style.css file)

```
.mydiv{
background: linear-gradient(white, blue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='blue', endColorstr='white'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(blue), to(white)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  blue,  white); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
```

This gives a cross-browser compatible CSS.
Note that the top color was blue and bottom was white, you can change it according to your requirement.
Enjoy!